# Need help Creating a Datatable from a list with possible null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I need some assistance in the best way to edit my DataTable to handle possible null values.

In this instance their is potential for any of the items from the list being added to the DataTable to be null. I'm looking for the best way to account for those null values when creating the DataTable so when I insert this into MSSQL I don't run into errors.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the DataTable:

```
public DataTable ConvertListToCustomDataTable(List<RootObject> listOfItems)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("DateCreated");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthCode");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthDateCreated");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthLevel");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthID");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthCategoryName");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthName");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthCategoryDateUpdated");
    table.Columns.Add("DepthDateUpdated");
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("ID");
    table.Columns.Add("CategoryCode");
    table.Columns.Add("CategoryDateCreated");
    table.Columns.Add("CategoryDateUpdated");
    table.Columns.Add("CategoryID");
    table.Columns.Add("CategoryName");
    table.Columns.Add("Code");

    foreach (var item in listOfItems)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();

        row["DateCreated"] = item.DateCreated;
        row["DepthCode"] = item.Depth.Code;
        row["DepthDateCreated"] = item.Depth.DateCreated;
        row["DepthLevel"] = item.Depth.Level;
        row["DepthID"] = item.Depth.ID;
        row["DepthCategoryName"] = item.Depth.Category.Name;
        row["DepthName"] = item.Depth.Name;
        row["DepthCategoryDateUpdated"] = item.Depth.Category.DateUpdated;
        row["DepthDateUpdated"] = item.Depth.DateUpdated;
        row["Name"] = item.Name;
        row["ID"] = item.ID;
        row["CategoryCode"] = item.Category.Code;
        row["CategoryDateCreated"] = item.Category.DateCreated;
        row["CategoryDateUpdated"] = item.Category.DateUpdated;
        row["CategoryID"] = item.Category.ID;
        row["CategoryName"] = item.Category.Name;
        row["Code"] = item.Code;

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the table columns to accept nulls.

```
 DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn("DateCreated");
 datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
```

I would put the Column names in an array and loop through them, ie something similar to this.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

string[] column = { "DateCreated", "DepthCode", "DepthDateCreated" };

foreach (var item in column)
{
    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(item);
    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    table.Columns.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: should i be making this change on the column or the rows? The column headers will not be null but the rows might contain some null data. If this does have to be made on the column then do i have to write this code for each column or just all together?